# TypeScipt properties dependent on boolean?

Tags: typescript, interface

is there a way in typescript to make an interface dependent on the value of something in that interface? What I'm trying to do is I have a box that can be optionally closable, and it's also optional wether or not we store that action to make it persistent, so I have an interface like this:

```
interface ButtonProps = { closable: boolean, closableKey?: string }
```

If closable is false, I don't want people to be able to set a closableKey and vice versa. Is this possible with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html):

```js
type ButtonProps = {
    closeable?: false;
} | {
    closeable: true;
    closeableKey: string;
};
```

This would result in the shown (non-)errors for the following examples:

[image: Examples]

Comment: You have used Union type and mentioned Intersection type. Please correct that

Answer (score 1):

You can use union type

```
type ButtonProps = {
    closable: false;
} | {
    closable: true;
    closableKey: string;
}

const props1: ButtonProps = {
    closable: true,
    closableKey: "",
};

const props2: ButtonProps = {
    closable: false,
};
```

If you have General props which you want to include in both, you can combine your types with intersection types

```
type GeneralProps = {
    name?: string;
}

type NotClosable = {
    closable: false;
} & GeneralProps;

type Closable = {
    closable: true;
    closableKey: string;
} & GeneralProps;

type ButtonProps = NotClosable | Closable;

const props1: ButtonProps = {
    closable: true,
    closableKey: "",
};

const props2: ButtonProps = {
    closable: false,
};
```